# Upper bound on the length of chordless cycles in d-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Given a $d$-regular graph with $n$ vertices is there a known (non-trivial) upper bound on the length of [chordless cycles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChordlessCycle.html) in it (presumably as a function of $d$ and $n$)? I wasn't able to find anything after some online searches. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a value K such that SOME chordless cycle must have length at most K?  Or do you want a value K such that all chordless cycles have length at most K?

Comment: Brendan@: It is the latter, i.e. a value K such that all chordless cycles have length at most K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say a chordless cycle $C$ has length $k$.
The number of edges between $C$ and $V-C$ is
$k(d-2)$.  Also, the number of edges from $V-C$ to $C$ is at most $(n-k)d$.  The solution is
$$k\le \biggl\lfloor
  \frac{nd}{2(d-1)}\biggr\rfloor.$$
This is often realised but I'm too lazy to figure out if it is always realised.

Answer (score 1):

If $d=2$, the trivial bound $n$ is sharp (take a cycle). For $d\ge 3$, the Moore bound tells you that the girth (length of a shortest cycle) is at most logarithmic in $n$ (roughly at most $2 \log(n)/\log(d-1)$). Since shortest cycles are chordless, this shows that there exist chordless cycles of length $O(\log n))$. Examples showing the asymptotic tightness of the Moore bound (for instance some constructions of Ramanujan graphs) also show that this is asymptotically best possible.

Comment: Louis@: I hope I didn't misunderstand it but the O(logn) bound is not an upper bound on *all* chordless cycles in a d-regular graph, right?

Comment: Right, sorry if I misunderstood your question, this was an upper bound on the size of some chordless cycle (not all of them).